# text slicing not working

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

template.html

```
{{list.report.description|default:"No description available"|slice:"45" }}{% if list.report.description|length > 45 %}...{% endif %}
```

1.This is slicing if character entered more than 45.

2.It produce problem while creating new report,if no description is given,it should display the default text as  "No description available" but instead it is displaying the text along with 3 dots.

2.No problem if the field is saved with empty,it is displaying default as "No description available".

Thanks

Comment: Note there is a typo in `{{list.report.discription|default:"No description available"|slice:"45" }}`: should `discription` be `description`?

Comment: No that is not the problem,this while editing in SO the mistake was  happened,sorry

Comment: If you remove all the slicing, does `{{list.report.description}}` give you accurate results?My  guess is NO.

Comment: @karthikr,i removed the slice and checked,it is ok no problem.

Comment: which version of django are you using? Are you sure you made no mistakes while transcribing ? This looks perfectly fine to me.

Comment: @karthikr,i am using Django 1.3.7,if i edit some thing in  that field and delete the same and save,the 3dots are not visible.Means an empty save if i perform the issue is not their.

Answer (score 1):

Although I am not entirely sure why your code isn't working, it's the "wrong" thing to do anyhow.

Try the truncatechars method instead: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#truncatechars

```
{{ value|truncatechars:9 }}
```

If value is `Joel is a slug`, the output will be `Joel i...`.

For Django 1.3 or older, use the following templatetag: http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/444/

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def truncatechars(s, num):
    """
    Truncates a word after a given number of chars  
    Argument: Number of chars to truncate after
    """
    length = int(num)
    string = []
    for word in s.split():
        if len(word) > length:
            string.append(word[:length]+'...')
        else:
            string.append(word)
    return u' '.join(string)
```

Comment: Very true, I've added an alternative for older Django versions :)